# How to append html elements after a div within the html body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html page that is built via index.html and javascript.
The html content has several buttons that are appended to the "body" element.
This works fine.

Now I want to append the content after a div element with id "body1" that is within the main body.
But I'm getting errors, of null elements.

If I append domElement1 to body, and I print the contents of document.body, the appended domElement1 shows up ok

```
document.body: body
  childNodes: NodeList(20)
    ...
    18: div#domElement1
```

If I append domElement1 to body1, and I print the contents of document.body, the appended domElement1 does NOT show up OK -
  I don't see div#domElement1. Instead I see "0: text"

```
document.body: body
  childNodes: NodeList(20)
    ...
    5: div#body1
      childNodes: NodeList(1)
        0: text
```

Below you can see the code changes to the code, and the html file.

How can I append html elements after a div within the html body?

Thanks

---

Code changes to the code:

1. In the javascript code, I changed the code from

   `$('body').append(domElement1);`

   to

   `let body1 = document.getElementById('body1');
      body1.append(domElement1);`

The html file - index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
...
        <script src="js/include/stats.js"></script>        
...

    </head>
    <body>        
        <div id="body1">
            <!-- <script type="module" src="main.js"></script> -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add directly by jquery

```
$('#body1').append(domElement1);
```

(`#` for element's id)